# Issue with system intents

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, calllog

I have a program that has a `broadcast receiver` that listens for Phone_State and then sends a user defined `intent`.

Well, my problem is that the system also sends out an `intent` (the one that I am trying to replace with my program) .

So I am trying to find a way to `CANCEL the systems intent`.

I have found that if i have a timer just wait for a little bit, then I can send mine after the systems, but that is not very good, and sometimes defeats the purpose of my program.

Also, i cannot set my program as a default because it is not a full dialer program. Just one action of it.

Someone please help me find how to listen for and cancel a system `intent/activity`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Someone please help me find how to
>   listen for and cancel a system
>   intent/activity

You cannot "cancel" an activity, period.

You cannot replace the dialer.

*If* the system `Intent` was sent via `sendOrderedBroadcast()`, then you can call `abortBroadcast()` from your `BroadcastReceiver`, and any lower-priority receivers will not get the broadcast. However, I have no evidence that `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is an ordered broadcast, and I sincerely hope it isn't.

Whatever you are trying to do probably should be accomplished via modifications to your own custom firmware.

Comment: So, you are saying that I cant just somehow overshadow the system intent, without just waiting for the system intent to go and then calling mine? And unfortunately I dont know how to listen for a specific activity... Is there a way to listen to activity manager for a specific activity?